# Notepad++ insert a word in one list

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of 90 picture names:

```
name1 
name2
name3
name4
...
```

I need to prepare the code like this:

```
<img alt="" src="/images/members/thumbnail-name1.gif" class="alignnone" width="36" height="36" />
<img alt="" src="/images/members/thumbnail-name2.gif" class="alignnone" width="36" height="36" />
<img alt="" src="/images/members/thumbnail-name3.gif" class="alignnone" width="36" height="36" />
  ...
```

Any idea how to do that with notepad++ to save time?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

Search what: `(.+)`
Replace with: `<img alt="" src="/images/members/thumbnail-$1.gif" class="alignnone" width="36" height="36" />`

Make sure you've checked `Regular Expression` and NOT checked `. matches newline`